# JavaScript validation change value on submit

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I need to set a form input value to -1 when submitted if nothing is entered. 
So far I have this function, but it doesn’t change the value to -1.

```
<form action="validate.php"
      method="post" onsubmit="return validate()" >

<input type="text" name="CategoryID" size="3" maxlength="3" onkeyup="checkCategoryID(this)"/>

function validate()
{
    var catID;
    catID = document.getElementsByName("CategoryID");

    if (catID.value == "")
        catID.value = -1;
    return true;

}
```

Comment: when you`re comparing strings in js you should use ===

Comment: Thanks, I didn’t know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code. First, JavaScript code should either be included in a separate javascript file or embedded inside `script` tags.

Second, you'll want to use `return false` instead of return true.

Also, the default behavior of a form, is for it to be submitted. You might want to pass in a parameter `event` and use the `event.preventDefault` method.

Also, `getElementsByName` returns a collection not a single element. You need to pass in an index like so

```
getElementsByName("categoryID")[0];
```

The form tag requires the closing tag `</form>`.

`catID.value == ""` is searching for an empty string. You can use a boolean instead. It's equivalent to `!catID.value`

Here is my temporary solution.

```
<form action="validate.php"
      method="post" onsubmit="validate()" >

<input type="text" name="CategoryID" size="3" maxlength="3" onkeyup="checkCategoryID(this)"/>
</form>

<script>   

    var catID = document.getElementsByName("CategoryID")[0];

    function validate() {

        if (!catID.value) {
            catID.value = -1;
            return false;
       }        
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Richard for your detailed reply, it’s much appreciated. If future, I’ll post the whole form code.